# Sending emails asynchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, email

In a part of our system a lot (I'm not sure how many, probably a couple thousand) of emails are being sent to the users at a specific time of the month. It seems this kills the server.
So I was asked to add the mailing of these emails to another part of the system that uses a Scheduler to do calculations.
The idea being that the Scheduler can then handle the sending of emails in parallel etc.

So I began looking at the code that I need to integrate with, and began reading on the Internet, and I'm thinking that perhaps I don't need to overhaul the emails into the Scheduler just yet.

It looks like they (the original programmers who no longer work at the company) didn't implement the sending of the emails asynchronously, so no wonder the server is being killed. It also made me wonder where the actual bottleneck is, would it even help to have the Scheduler implement a bunch of threads but still call the synchronous Send method...?

I have seen that SmtpClient has a SendMailAsync method. I have also seen that SmtpClient is considered obsolete and that MailKit is preferred.
The system uses .Net 4.5.2.

I haven't used Postman before, but I have managed to do some tests with a small number of email addresses. I compare the time between the current synchronous way of sending emails, and then I implemented async methods using SendMailAsync. The SendMailAsync functionality takes less time according to Postman.

So I want to change the implementation to use SendMailAsync, then after that I want to change it to use MailKit.

However, I'm not sure whether I am making other mistakes.

Here is the changed method to use SendMailAsync:

```
public async virtual Task<string> SendMailAsync(string[] emailAddresses, Dictionary<string, string> replacements, string body)
    {
        try
        {

            body = ReplaceProductName(replacements, body);

            // Intercept email if test email address is setup
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["testEmailAddress"]))
            {
                string emailAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["testEmailAddress"];
                using (MailMessage mail = mailDefinition.CreateMailMessage(emailAddress, replacements, body, new System.Web.UI.Control()))
                {
                    {
                        await client.SendMailAsync(mail);
                        log.Info("The following email was sent to " + emailAddress + " Replacements: " + replacements.ToDebugString());
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                using (MailMessage mail = mailDefinition.CreateMailMessage(string.Join(",", emailAddresses), replacements, body, new System.Web.UI.Control()))
                {
                    {
                        await client.SendMailAsync(mail);
                        log.Info("The following email was sent to " + string.Join(",", emailAddresses) + " Replacements: " + replacements.ToDebugString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("The following email could not be sent. Replacements: " + replacements.ToDebugString());
            log.Error(ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }
        return string.Join(",", emailAddresses);
    }
```

Is it okay to use the using block? I read somewhere something about it, but perhaps it was concerning the method SendAsync. I'm not sure.

Any further advice and suggestions would be appreciated. :-)

**UPDATE**

It seems the emails are sent through Gmail's smtp server. I found this in a helper class:

```
public void Send(string toEmail, string subject, string body)
    {
        new SmtpClient
        {
            Port = 587,
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            EnableSsl = true,
            Timeout = 10000,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("somenoreply@gmail.com", "SomePassword")
        }.Send(new MailMessage("some.lab@gmail.com", toEmail, subject, body)
        {
            IsBodyHtml = true,
            BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
            DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure
        });
    }
```

**UPDATE 2**

Upon further investigation, it seems that some emails are being sent from a Microsoft SQL server stored procedure which uses a cursor. This causes trouble on the SQL server.
I initially thought it was a different server being affected, but it is actually the SQL server being slowed down by this stored proc sending emails.
This stored proc calls another stored procedure, which with a few more methods inbetween eventually calls the method given above (SendMailAsync).
However, currently the synchronous version of the above method is still the one being used in the system.

It seems that less emails than I originally thought are being sent via Gmail's smtp. The limit on Gmail's side (I think 2000 per day) is not being hit at present.

So my question is, would implementing the asynchronous version, SendMailAsync also be an improvement to the performance of the SQL Server, or is the cursor in the stored procedure itself a greater problem?

Here is the stored proc:

```
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Interface_PayslipEmails]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROC [dbo].[sp_Interface_PayslipEmails](@Periods VARCHAR(MAX),@Resourcetag INT = 0)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Collection VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Periodid INT
DECLARE @PortalURL VARCHAR(500) = (SELECT TOP 1 Value from [System Variables] WHERE [Variable] =  'Portal URL')
DECLARE @PeriodTable TABLE ([Period id] INT )
IF @Resourcetag = 0 SET @Resourcetag = NULL
INSERT INTO @PeriodTable
(
    [Period id]
)
select [Value] FROM dbo.fn_Split(@Periods,',') 

SET @Periodid = (SELECT MAX([period id]) FROM @PeriodTable)

SET @Collection = (SELECT dbo.fn_GetCalendarCollectionfromPeriod(@Periodid))
SET @Collection = UPPER(REPLACE(@Collection,'Payrun ',''))

UPDATE I
SET I.[Status] = 'Processed'
FROM [dbo].[PER REM Infoslip] I
INNER JOIN @PeriodTable P
ON I.[Period id] = P.[Period id]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Calendar Periods] cp
ON P.[Period id]  = cp.[Period ID]
AND [cp].[RunType] = 'Normal'
AND I.[Resource Tag] =ISNULL(@Resourcetag,I.[Resource Tag])
 

SELECT DISTINCT I.[Resource Tag],[I].[E-mail Address] 
INTO #Employees
FROM [dbo].[PER REM Infoslip] I
INNER JOIN @PeriodTable P
ON I.[Period id] = P.[Period id]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Calendar Periods] cp
ON P.[Period id]  = cp.[Period ID]
AND [cp].[RunType] = 'Normal' --only normal periods available for now
WHERE ISNULL([I].[E-mail Address],'') != ''
AND I.[status] = 'Processed'
AND I.[Resource Tag] = ISNULL(@Resourcetag,I.[Resource Tag])

/* declare variables */
DECLARE @RT INT
DECLARE @EmailAddress VARCHAR(150)
DECLARE @Message VARCHAR(MAX) =''

IF @Collection LIKE '%Feb%2020%'
SET @Message = 'Friendly Reminder. All excess leave will be forfeited on the 28th February as per previous communications.'

DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR FOR SELECT [Resource Tag],[E-mail Address] FROM #Employees
OPEN cursor_name

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_name INTO @RT,@EmailAddress

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    --API Call to send email
    PRINT @Collection
    PRINT @PortalURL
        EXEC Sp_SendPayslipEmail @PortalURL,@RT,@EmailAddress,@Collection,@Message

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_name INTO @RT,@EmailAddress
END

CLOSE cursor_name
DEALLOCATE cursor_name
END 

GO
```

Here is the next stored procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_SendPayslipEmail]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Sp_SendPayslipEmail](
  @Hostname NVARCHAR(MAX) 
, @ResourceTag INT
, @Email VARCHAR(256)
, @Period     NVARCHAR(256)
, @Message VARCHAR(MAX))
AS

DECLARE @now VARCHAR(MAX) =  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), GETDATE(), 13)

DECLARE @OBJECT INT
DECLARE @RESPONSETEXT VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @URL NVARCHAR(MAX) =  'https://' + @Hostname + '/payslip/sendpayslipemail?resourceTag=' + CAST(@ResourceTag AS VARCHAR(50))+ '&emailAddress=' + @Email  + '&period=' + @Period + '&message=' + ISNULL(@Message,'') + '&_=' + @now


EXEC sp_OACreate 'Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0', @OBJECT OUT
EXEC sp_OAMethod @OBJECT, 'setTimeouts', NULL, 5000, 5000, 30000, 300000

EXEC sp_OAMethod @OBJECT, 'open', NULL, 'get', @URL, 'false'
EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @object
EXEC sp_OAMethod @OBJECT, 'send'
EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @object
EXEC sp_OAMethod @OBJECT, 'responseText',@RESPONSETEXT OUTPUT
SELECT @RESPONSETEXT
EXEC sp_OADestroy @OBJECT
EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @object

GO
```

Here is the action method:

```
public ActionResult SendPayslipEmail(int resourceTag, string emailAddress, string period, string message = "")
    {
      using (ESSDataContext ctx = new ESSDataContext())
      {
        try
        {
          string systemUrl = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
          var displayName = MyDetailsDataManager.GetDisplayName(resourceTag);
          new PayslipNotificationMailSender().SendPayslipReadyNotification(emailAddress, systemUrl, period, displayName, message);
          ctx.sp_ESS_PayslipEmailAudit(resourceTag, emailAddress, period, "Sent", "");
      return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      ctx.sp_ESS_PayslipEmailAudit(resourceTag, emailAddress, period, "Failed", ex.Message);
      log.Error($"Error sending payslip email. Error: {ex.Message}");
      return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the method that calls the SendMail message, which I have tried to change to SendMailAsync above:

```
public void SendPayslipReadyNotification(string employeeEmail, string systemUrl, string period, string displayName, string message = "")
{
  try
  {
    mailDefinition.Subject = "Payslip Generated";

    string body =
      System.IO.File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory +
                                 "App_Data/Templates/MailTemplates/PayslipNotification.html");
    Dictionary<string, string> replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    replacements.Add("<%LoginUrl%>", systemUrl);
    replacements.Add("<%PayslipPeriod%>", period);
    replacements.Add("<%UserName%>", displayName);
    replacements.Add("<%Message%>", message);
    SendMail(employeeEmail, replacements, body);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    log.Error("SendPayslipReadyNotification failed for :" + employeeEmail);
    Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(e);
    throw e;
  }
}
```

I didn't write these last methods /stored procedures. It's just what is in the system currently, and I want to improve it. I'm not knowledgeable regarding web programming nor sql, which in this case is definitely a disadvantage.
So I don't know whether implementing async functionality in the C# methods will actually improve the SQL server's performance?

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview. While the question itself is well-suited to this site, your code isn't completely reviewable on its own. Some further information might be necessary for reviewers, e.g. `ReplaceProductName` or `CreateMailMessage` and what `client` is. Note that I personally don't know anything about the .NET platform, and you might disregard this comment if both are well-known in the community.

Comment: Sending a couple thousand emails at once isn't a good idea. You might be better off using a service like https://postmarkapp.com/ .

Comment: In support of the don't do this argument I have a story - I have worked on a website running on an on-premise box and emails were routed through the office Exchange Server - a feature was implemented that did something similar (actuall sending around 50,000 emails) - this flooded Exchange Server meaning that no-one in the office was able to send/receive emails for around eight hours --- SMTP is just the protocol, you need to understand how the emails are going to be handled downstream

Comment: @Zeta, thank you, you make a valid point. For now, it doesn't seem too relevant to the main thrust of my question though.

Comment: @BCdotWEB, thank you, I will be looking at their services as an option.

Comment: @StewartRitchie, please see the update. I found that Gmail's smtp server is being used. Would it be an improvement to use a service such as Postmark then? 
Would it still make a difference to implement the async methods?

Comment: Rate limits may apply when using Google's smtp server https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/157

Comment: If you are sending transactional emails one at time in response to user actions, for example verifying an email address when a user registers, then dispatching then asynchronously is going to be good.

Comment: For a batch send scenario - use a provider like PostMark or MailChimp etc

Comment: @StewartRitchie, please see Update 2.

Comment: Not really a code review question, but you should be aware of SQL Server database mail, that's a standard way to send mail from SQL Server.

Comment: @GeorgeBarwood, yes this started out as a Code Review for the SendMailAsync method, but after the initial comments and further investigation that I have done, the focus has shifted. So this code works, but I'm wondering how it could be improved and optimised, and in that sense, I think it suits Code Review rather than Stack Overflow. But I'm open to move it if others feel it doesn't fit here.